# Frazo memstara kun participo adverba

Tags: adverbs, participles

Ĉu estas ĝuste uzi tian ĉi frazon kiel, ekzemple, staton, sen ĉeffrazo/ĉefverbo, precipe (sed ne nepre nur) en "UX"?

> "Analizante dosierojn..." (sur statbreto, anstataŭ "analizado je dosieroj" aŭ eĉ "dosieroj estas analizataj")
> "Lavante la katon!" (anstataŭ "mi lavas la katon", kiel respondo al demando ekz "Kion faras vi?")

Mi kredas ke tia uzado estas *teĥnike* ĝusta, ĉar tuta tia frazo *tre tre teĥnike* estas kvazaŭ unu adverbo (laŭ mia kompreno), kaj adverbo povas memstari kiel ekz ekkrio. Ĉu regulo tro fleksita?

> D: "Kiel fartas ĉiu el vi?"
> R0: "Bone!" (t.e. "Mi bone fartas.")
> R1: "Sane!" (t.e. "Mi sane fartas.")
> R2: "Pensante pri amorado!" (t.e. freneze "Mi {pensante pri amorado} fartas.")

"Pensante pri amorado" *teĥnike* estas la maniero, en kiu fartas la ulo R2, kvazaŭ tiu tuta frazparto estas unu adverbo, ĉu ne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kvankam en la angla oni povas uzi adverbajn participojn memstare por montri daŭron

- *Analysing files…*

oni ne povas uzi adverbajn participojn tiel en Esperanto. Estas pli bone, se vi rigardas adverbajn participojn kiel frazekvivalentojn. Ekzemple

- Analizante dosierojn mi malkovris tutan aron de malnovaj fotoj

egalas la frazon

- Kiam mi analizis dosierojn, mi malkovris…

(Notu, ke en Esperanto la subjekto de tia frazekvivalento ĉiam devas esti la sama kiel en la ĉeffrazo de la ekvivalenta kompleta frazo.)

Do en fasado de programo vi povas havi:

- Analizo de dosieroj (progresas)
- Analizataj dosieroj: <nombro>

Comment: Kiam «de» estus ambigua (t.e. ne tie, ĉar evidente estas dosieroj, kiuj estas analizataj, ne analizantaj), ĉu ĝustus ankaŭ «je»? Ekzemple, eble estas ke pli ol unu umo analizas la samajn dosierojn. Ekzemple "analizo je dosiero #2 de analizilo #0...analizo je dosiero #2 de analizilo #1...(ktp)". Eveidente, ne senchavus ke dosiero analizus analizilon, do tiu estas nur ekzemplo.

Comment: Pravas, ke "de" estas tre multsenca. Kiam la frazo havas pasivan participon, "de" ĉiam montras la aganton, sed miaj ekzemploj ne havas tiajn, do ne estas risko de mikso, kiel vi mem konstatis. Se estas pliaj agantoj, oni eble povas montri tiujn per [_fare de_](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/de/aga_o-vorto.html): "analizo de dosiero #1 fare de la analizilo A".

Comment: Ĝis nun, ambaŭ respondoj ja interkonsentas, sed mi neniam aŭdis pri tiu regulo, kiu diras ke memstara “~ante ion” estas malĝusta. Kie mi povas legi pli pri ĝi? Laŭ miaj trovoj, PMEG ne diras tion, ĝi nur ĉirkaŭiras tiun temon.

Comment: [PMEG §28.2 Participoj kiel E-vortoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/e-vortoj.html): "Tiam ĝi montras kroman agon, kiu rilatas al la subjekto de tiu verbo. Anstataŭ diri du frazojn, unu por ĉiu ago, oni kunmetas la frazojn al unu."

Comment: Sed tio ne estas malpermeso pri io ajn. Ĉu la problemo estas manko de subjekto?

Comment: @marcus, mi resonas tiel: Laŭ PMEG e-finaĵa participo "montras **kroman** agon, kiu rilatas al la subjekto de tiu verbo". Memstara participa frazo malhavas kaj la subjekton kaj la ĉefverbon. Notu, ke oni ne povas uzi eĉ [sensubjektajn verbojn](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/sensubjektaj.html) tiel memstare, ĉar mankas la ĉefverbo.

Answer (score 1):

`Analizante dosierojn` rolas kiel adverbo, ĝi iel postulas daŭrigon kaj donas neniun informon pri la subjekto:

```
Analizante dosierojn mi malkovris tutan aron de malnovaj fotoj
```

En fasado de programo oni, laŭ mi, listigu agojn:

```
Analizo de dosieroj
```

aŭ aĵojn:

```
Dosieroj analizataj
```

Kelkaj, malĝuste laŭ mi, sed tamen kompreneble pro influo alilingva, uzas sensubjektan formon jenan:

```
Analizanta dosierojn
```

Mi tamen opinias memstaran `Analizante dosierojn` malĝusta.